# Project dependency via file instead of assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have projects A, B, and C.

- Project A: a netstandard library.
- Project B: a console app, depending on project A and producing a database file "B.file" when run.
- Project C: a netstandard library, depending on "B.file" (as an embedded resource). It is referenced by UWP, Xamarin.IOS, and Xamarin.Android projects.

I would like C always to have access to an updated "B.file". So I would like to set up dependencies so that when C is built, A is built and B is run beforehand if A has changed. C cannot depend on B in the normal way as it is a console project. So how can this be done?

Possible solutions:

- A post-build step on A to run B, and have C depend on A. I am concerned that if the build tooling/linker is bad, it may unnecessarily deploy the assemblies in A when releasing UWP, Xamarin.IOS, and Xamarin.Android projects. Is this a valid concern?
- Some sort of watcher?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with help of pre-build and post-build events.

I assume all 3 projects are either in one solution or inside one directory. And Project A is added as a reference for Project B, i.e. B depends on A.

Now all 3 projects should have a similar directory structure as below,

.\SolutionDirectory\ProjectA\

.\SolutionDirectory\ProjectB\
.\SolutionDirectory\ProjectB\bin\Release\ProjectB.exe
.\SolutionDirectory\ProjectB\bin\Release\B.file <- This will be generated when we run **Project B**, path could be different

.\SolutionDirectory\ProjectC\
.\SolutionDirectory\ProjectC\bin\Release\B.file <- This is referred inside **Project C** (as an embedded resource). Path could be different.

Set incremental build for project A and B, so that unnecessary builds are avoided when nothing is modified. Here is [a guide to set up incremental build.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally?view=vs-2019)

**Solution 1: Pre-build event for Project C**
Put below commands as your pre-build event for **Project C**. To do so follow these steps -> right click Project C -> Properties -> Build Events -> Pre-build event command line:
Make sure you have MSBuild on your machine for this pre-build event to work. It exists at path like : C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe

```
msbuild $(SolutionDir)ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj /p:Configuration=Release 
START $(SolutionDir)ProjectB\bin\Release\ProjectB.exe
Rem add delay if needed
SLEEP 10
xcopy /y $(SolutionDir)ProjectB\bin\Release\B.File $(SolutionDir)ProjectC\bin\Release\
```

First command will build Project B(Since B depends on A, msbuild will build A first and then B).
Second command will run Project B which will generate **B.file**
And final command will copy **B.file** from B to C.

This solution will ensure that B always have access to latest B.file. And since we have set up incremental buils, it will not unnecessarily build files in Project A and B.

**Solution 2: Post-build event for Project A and Project B**
Put below commands in your post-build event for **Project A and C**, so that whenever you make changes to project Project A or Project B and build it, it will execute Project B to generate latest B.file and copy it to Project C.

```
START $(SolutionDir)ProjectB\bin\Release\ProjectB.exe
Rem add delay if needed
SLEEP 10
xcopy /y $(SolutionDir)ProjectB\bin\Release\B.File $(SolutionDir)ProjectC\bin\Release\
```

This solution 2 makes sure that Project C gets latest B.file, but not always. Because, in case you make changes to A or B and forgot to build it, C will not get latest B.file.
So solution 1 is preferred. Though it will always build Project A and B, it should not be a concern, because incremental build for A and B will not unnecessarily build unchanged files.

Comment: pre-build event for project C can be done without additional .bat file. But it will built project A every time even when there are no any changes.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Agree. This pre-build  ensures that we get latest B.file every time. Another variant could be to have post-build event for Project B to copy B.file from Project B to Project C. But what if there are changes in A or B and B is not built, then we can not have latest B.file for C

Comment: `Another variant could be to have post-build event for Project B to copy B.file from Project B to Project C. But what if there are changes in A or B and B is not built, then we can not have latest B.file for C` Exactly. That's almost the same as current approach

Comment: @FoggyFinder But the approach in answer will ensure that C always have access to updated "B.file", which is OP's major concern. And that too without including anything from A into output of C.

Comment: @FoggyFinder We can avoid unnecessary builds with the help of incremental build for A and B. I have edited answer to add incremental build.

Comment: Thanks for the effort in this detailed writeup @as.if.I.code . One little issue with solution 1 is that it always runs and copies the file, which then leads to project C being considered changed even when the file is identical (because of the file timestamp maybe). However it may be the best of the current possible approaches.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie I think ideally you will build Project C only when you have made some changes to it. And when the pre-build event completes, it will anyways build Project C subsequently. So this should not be problem. But if it is triggered without a change then your concern is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly. You wish to make "Project C" dependent on "Project B", and "Project B" dependent on "Project A".

In Visual Studio you can set dependencies from "Project->Dependencies".

There you select from tab 1(Dependencies) your selected project.  (In this case Project B)

Then from the selected project you select "Depends on:" (In this case checkbox for Project A)

So if I break your Project A, B, and C into levels 1, 2 and 3.

Project 3 Relies on Project 2.

Project 2 relies on Project 1.

So if 1 is not built, "Project 1" will build, then "Project 2" before "Project 3".

And now we come into the second tab 2 (Build Order). From top to bottom, this will show your current build order.

If there are no changes to the previous requirement and it is built. It should not need to be rebuilt. (There might be a sneaky setting for this in Visual Studio).

If you imagine your solution configuration with 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on, instead of A, B, C. 
The following image should be an example of what your solution will look like.

[image: "Level 1 Base Target" Requires "Level 0 Library Target"]

Comment: This is basically the first of the "possible solutions" I gave, so are you able to confirm that build tooling will typically remove the code in project A when releasing C?

Comment: With the solution I'm working with now, if i build level 3,  Level 3 is dependant on Level 2, Level 1 and Level 0.       So the build then starts to build from level 0 then finishes with Level 3...     Remove the code? -It will "rebuild" the files in OutputDirectory. Not sure what you mean with the build tooling to remove code.      If you mean the "B.file", if this is made from project B-building it will be replaced yes.

Comment: The code in project A should not appear in the output assembly.

Comment: I see i misread a vital part of your question.  I would suspect the following. As long as your configuration is to output the files into the common OutputDirectory. The files from "A" wont reach output for project "C".           Could the following idea work?  As your possible solution, but with a twist:   -> Set Project B dependent on Project A.  Then use "Pre-Build configuration" for Project C to run the file from B (remake it just before you build Project C).

Comment: `Set Project B dependent on Project A. Then use "Pre-Build configuration" for Project C to run the file from B (remake it just before you build Project C).` it will build project A every time even when there are no any changes.